# "Diagonalizing" structure constants

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Assume a generic algebra over a field. (In my case it's not a Lie algebra, although surely it somehow is connected, but an associative but noncommutative tangle algebra.) Under which conditions can you choose the bases $e_i$ such that all generators are projectors: $e_i\bigotimes{v}=const(v)*e_i$ for all i and members v of the vector space? (Or, less contrieved, $e_i\bigotimes{e_j}=\delta_{ij}*e_i$.) And if the structure constants are given in a non-diagonal base $E_i\bigotimes{E_j}=\Sigma{c_{ij}^k*E_k}$, how do you actually construct the projectors?

Comment: Assuming a generic algebra, where do you get your vector space from? Are you embedding your algebra into a matrix algebra/an endomorphism ring? If yes: which one?

Comment: Don't know much about algebra...isn't it sufficient to give the field and the multiplication rule (via the structure constants) to define the algebra?

Comment: Yes, that should work. However, that doesn't answer the question where the vector space comes into play... Or are you considering the algebra itself as a vector space, so are the $v$ elements of your algebra?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Say (random example), e1°e1=0,e2°e2=e2,e1°e2=e2°e1=e1+e2, the vector space consists of all v=a°e1+b°e2 with scalar a,b, and I look for p,q so that (p°e1+q°e2)°(v-r)=0 for all v (where scalar r depends on v). (Sorry, n00b at TeX, using ° for both algebra and scalar *)

Comment: Do you know of orthogonal idempotents (see for example here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444473/intuition-for-idempotents-orthogonal-idempotents). They should be mentioned and discussed in most algebra textbooks when proving structural results about finite dimensional algebras.

Comment: THX for the buzzword :-) I more hoped that the orthogonal idempotents could have been directly expressed in the structure constants, even graphically (at least for commutative and associative °) but so there.